# Switch example from UITableViewController to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am relatively new in iOS, I have found an example of accordion table view that I need. But the thing is that example is TableViewController and I need to implement TableView inside viewController. Can you please help me. What I have tried to do is create tableView, declare it in the h file as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *MyTb;
```

and then change all appearances of self.tableView to self.MyTb but it did not work, oh also changed

```
AccordionTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

to

```
AccordionTableViewController : UIViewController
```

So here is the original code, please help me and provide some guiadance to it, thanks.

h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AccordionTableViewController : UITableViewController {
NSArray *topItems;
NSMutableArray *subItems; // array of arrays

int currentExpandedIndex;
}

@end
```

m file:

```
#import "AccordionTableViewController.h"

#define NUM_TOP_ITEMS 20
#define NUM_SUBITEMS 6

@implementation AccordionTableViewController

- (id)init {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    topItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self topLevelItems]];
    subItems = [NSMutableArray new];
    currentExpandedIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < [topItems count]; i++) {
        [subItems addObject:[self subItems]];
    }
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark - Data generators

- (NSArray *)topLevelItems {
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TOP_ITEMS; i++) {
    [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", i + 1]];
}

return items;
}   

- (NSArray *)subItems {
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
int numItems = arc4random() % NUM_SUBITEMS + 2;

for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SubItem %d", i + 1]];
}

return items;
}

#pragma mark - View management

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [topItems count] + ((currentExpandedIndex > -1) ? [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : 0);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"ParentCell";
static NSString *ChildCellIdentifier = @"ChildCell";

BOOL isChild =
currentExpandedIndex > -1
&& indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
&& indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

UITableViewCell *cell;

if (isChild) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChildCellIdentifier];
}
else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
}


if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (isChild) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - currentExpandedIndex - 1];
}
else {
    int topIndex = (currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex)
    ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count]
    : indexPath.row;

    cell.textLabel.text = [topItems objectAtIndex:topIndex];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
}

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
BOOL isChild =
currentExpandedIndex > -1
&& indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
&& indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

if (isChild) {
    NSLog(@"A child was tapped, do what you will with it");
    return;
}

[self.tableView beginUpdates];

if (currentExpandedIndex == indexPath.row) {
    [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
    currentExpandedIndex = -1;
}
else {

    BOOL shouldCollapse = currentExpandedIndex > -1;

    if (shouldCollapse) {
        [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
    }

    currentExpandedIndex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : indexPath.row;

    [self expandItemAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
}

[self.tableView endUpdates];

}

- (void)expandItemAtIndex:(int)index
{
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *currentSubItems = [subItems objectAtIndex:index];
int insertPos = index + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < [currentSubItems count]; i++) {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertPos++ inSection:0]];
}
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
//[indexPaths release];
}

- (void)collapseSubItemsAtIndex:(int)index
{
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = index + 1; i <= index + [[subItems objectAtIndex:index] count]; i++)
{
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
}
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//[indexPaths release];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[topItems release];
[subItems release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you set your view controller as your delegate and datasource for the table view?

Comment: You should just be able to create an `IBOutlet UITableView *tableView` property and then connect it in image builder.  As long as you have set the delegate and datasource as @KerrM said, you should be good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set your view controller as delegate and datasource of your tableview:

```
@interface AccordionTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

in your header file and in `viewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.MyTb.delegate = self;
  self.MyTb.dataSource = self;
}
```

Or you can set the datasource and delegate in Storyboard. You must also make sure you have connected the table view to `MyTb` IBOutlet in storyboard.

Comment: I get error on self.tableView that says Propery 'tableView' not found on object of type 'AccordionTableView'

Comment: Ok, now it works, but my table is empty and should be populated

Comment: Have you connected your table view to the outlet in storyboard?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to make sure you've configured it all correctly. If that breakpoint doesn't get triggered, put one in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and make sure you're returning the correct number of rows. If none of them get called, you've not wired up your datasource/delegate/table view appropriately.